# Number of delayed_job works on system reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm using the delayed_job Ruby gem just fine.

It defaults to a single worker, so I've gone ahead and done:

```
script/delayed_job stop
script/delayed_job -n 5 start
```

to ensure there are 5 workers.

However, when I reboot (or when the system decides to reboot), the Rails app boots back up with only a single delayed_job worker.

How can I change the default number of workers? It doesn't seem to be listed at https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the mechanism which ensured delayed_job started up on reboot was being controlled in my scenario by the 'whenever' gem's config/schedule.rb.

The number of jobs may also change if you're using Capistrano with delayed_job recipes. You'll have to ensure the two numbers are shared correctly.

Comment: Hi. What "recipie" did you find for your Capistrano config?
I'm using "foreman" to export things to upstart scripts.